# Scaling TwentyEleven theme for resolution

Tags: wordpress, scale, css

I have made my first [website](http://strandservice.fi) in WordPress based on the TwentyEleven theme. I have understood that it is supposed to scale to screen resolution, which it does not. I guess that i have broken something with some of my minimal edits in the CSS file.

Any idea on how I can find out where I have edited something that could have broken the scale function?

Is there a way to scale the website by default the same way the viewer can do manualy in their browser?

Comment: are you worried about the sidebar?

Comment: Pastebin.com has a function to compare two versions. Download a fresh copy and check the CSS diff. Learn how to use a child theme, it's easy and allows to update the parent theme without losing your changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sidebar-
replace your css of #secondary with

```
#secondary {
   float:left;
   width:25%;
}
```

and remove the max-height and max-width styles from the image.

Comment: Thank you. Replaced the #secoundary part but i cant find the max height and width in the .css file, i tried to find it manually and by using a compare tool to compare the original .css file.

Comment: its inline css. so it should be in the php file or it is being added using js